# Merge dataframes by a common column, but add columns with the same title together

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to figure out how to join two dataframes by a common column, and then add together the other similar columns.

**Inputs**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [0, 1, 3], 'value': [2, 2, 2]})
```

**Result**

```
df3 = {'timestamp': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'value': [3, 4, 3, 6]}
```

because

```
1 + 2 = 3
2 + 2 = 4
3 + 0 = 3
4 + 2 = 6
```

Comment: Ok, so what happened with your attempts? Did you get errors?

Comment: "add together the other similar columns." Why are the columns similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) + [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [0, 1, 3], 'value': [2, 2, 2]})

r = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('timestamp', as_index=False).sum()

print(r)
```

**Output**

```
   timestamp  value
0          0      3
1          1      4
2          2      3
3          3      6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `timestamp` as your index and add the dataframes together. You will need to use `add` with `fill_value` set to `0` for your missing data points:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('timestamp')
df2 = df2.set_index('timestamp')
result = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)

result

           value
timestamp       
0            3.0
1            4.0
2            3.0
3            6.0
```

If you want to keep `timestamp` as a column, just use `reset_index` to move it back:

```
result.reset_index()

   timestamp  value
0          0    3.0
1          1    4.0
2          2    3.0
3          3    6.0
```